# how can I get this sentence? the impact that everything you do has on climate change

Tags: word-meaning

> a: I don’t really get what carbon footprint means.
>   b: Oh, well, it means... I guess... **the impact that everything you do has on climate change.**

I encountered the sentence above in the movie...

What is 'the impact that~ climate change' exactly?

does it mean 'Everything you do can make an impact on climate change?

I don't know exactly 'have on'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare:

> Heat *has an effect on* wax. It makes the wax soft.
>
> {Everything you do} {has an effect on} the climate.

**X has an effect on Y = X affects Y**

The phrase "carbon footprint" is a coinage that refers to the cumulative effect everything you do has on the climate.

Alternatively:

The phrase "carbon footprint" is a coinage that refers to the cumulative effect on the climate of everything you do.

The phrase "carbon footprint" is a coinage that refers to the cumulative effect of  everything you do on the climate.

> The book is about the effect of acid rain on crops.
>
> The books is about acid rain's effect on crops.
>
> The book is about the effect acid rain has on crops.
>
> The book is about how acid rain affects crops.
>
> The book is about the effect on crops that acid rain has.